# RichTextBox not being updated by a Delegate / BackGroundWorker

Tags: vb.net

I have a RichTextBox on a Windows Form that I wish to update with 'checkpoints' as I go through an XML building process.

I have a Class called 'LogFiles' that has the Delegate for the RichTextBox

```
Public Delegate Sub AppendRichTextBoxDelegate(ByVal RTB As RichTextBox, ByVal txt As String)
```

In that Class I have the Sub to Append the RTB

```
Public Shared Sub AppendRichTextBox(ByVal RTB As RichTextBox, ByVal txt As String)
    Try
        If RTB.InvokeRequired Then
            RTB.Invoke(New AppendRichTextBoxDelegate(AddressOf AppendRichTextBox), New Object() {RTB, txt})
        Else
            RTB.AppendText(txt & Environment.NewLine)
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(MsgBox(ex.Message & Environment.NewLine & Environment.NewLine & ex.StackTrace))
    End Try

End Sub
```

Now when I call my BackGroundWorker

```
Public Sub BGW1ProcessFile_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BGW1ProcessFile.DoWork

    LogFiles.AppendRichTextBox(LogFileRTB, "Starting")

    LogFiles.CreateLog()

    Interchange.StartXML()

End Sub
```

That AppendRichTextBox works as expected and updates the RTB in real time, HOWEVER when I then stop into 'Interchange.StartXML' that also contains an AppendRichTextBox it does not update the RTB from within that Sub.

When the BackGroundWorker finishes the AppendRichTextBox for for the RunWorkerCompleted Event works as expected.

Why does the AppendRichTextBox Sub I have created with the delegate work on the BackGroundWorker Process but does not work on the Sub that is launched as part of the BackGroundWorker Process?

Its pickling my head a little bit, any assistance would be appreciated.

Regards,

James

Comment: Does Invoke require all args wrapped in an Object array like that in VB? I know thread start does, but in C#, invoke doesn't.

Comment: Why complicating things so much with the very GUI-thread-friendly BackgroundWorker? If you use its in-built methods everything will surely work fine. Why not relying on the ProgressChanged event?

Comment: Varocarbas, I agree with using that however at each 'point' in the StartXML Sub I want to output a different message to the RTB. i.e. Starting This, Processing XYZ, Processing ABC, Upoading to FTP. etc.

Comment: Shall I write a short sample code to explain what I mean?

Comment: @varocarbas please do :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained via comments, the `BackgroundWorker` is precisely meant to deal with the 2-thread situations involving GUI + another thread. That's why its in-built functionalities can gracefully account for the most likely situations.

In your case (i.e., regularly updating GUI elements from the BGW thread), you should rely on the `ProgressChanged` event. Here you have a sample code clearly showing how to use it:

```
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        BGW1ProcessFile.WorkerReportsProgress = True
        BGW1ProcessFile.RunWorkerAsync()

    End Sub

    Private Sub BGW1ProcessFile_ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles BGW1ProcessFile.ProgressChanged

        'You can include here as complex modifications on the GUI as 
        'required. Just store anything in e.UserState, as shown below

        RTB.Text = RTB.Text & e.UserState.ToString & Environment.NewLine

    End Sub

    Private Sub modifyRTB(caseNo As Integer)

        'Here you are calling the aforementioned ProgressChanged event.

        BGW1ProcessFile.ReportProgress(0, "This is case " & caseNo.ToString)

    End Sub 

    Private Sub BGW1ProcessFile_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BGW1ProcessFile.DoWork

        BGW1ProcessFile.ReportProgress(0, "We are in the BGW thread now")

        modifyRTB(1)
        modifyRTB(2)
        modifyRTB(3)

    End Sub

    Private Sub BGW1ProcessFile_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BGW1ProcessFile.RunWorkerCompleted

        RTB.Text = RTB.Text & Environment.NewLine & "We are outside the BWG thread now"

    End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Varo, thank you for your sample but I still have the same issue. Calling the BGW1ProcessFile.ReportPress from within the 'Interchange' Class is not firing off the Report Progress and therefore not populating the RTB. It just steps over the Call.

Bear in mind from your sample the DoWork section is not calling a Sub that is contained in another Class. I can get the RTB to update if I am the ReportProgress into 'DoWork' but it is not working wtihin the Sub that DoWork calls.

I am reluctant to move all the code from the Sub directly in the DoWork Sub to keep it organised.

Comment: I do 'Main.BGW1ProcessFile.ReportProgress(0,"xyz") which is the Class the BGW is in, it just steps over.

Comment: Varocarbas, I have bitten the bullet and done away with the Interchange Class and just moved all my code into the 'DoWork' section of the BGW, your above method then worked and although it is a little bit messy, I can get over it. Thank you for your precise method above.

Comment: @Lynchie No problem. But why are you saying that my code is messy? It is quite clear. Although the required methodology (not by me, but by the BackgroundWorker) is a bit complex. That's why you had some problems to understand it in a first moment and why I considered that writing a sample code (= the simplest version of this implementation) was required. Your previous approach was the messy one; this one represents the right way to do things (but some times things are complex; to not be mixed-up with messiness, where simple things are done in an unnecessarily complex way) :)

Comment: Hi Varo,

I am not saying YOUR code is messy, I'm saying the fact my own code was seperated into their own Classes and Subs but to get your method working within the 'ReportProgress' Sub I have had to do away with the seperate Classes and Subs I had.

Comment: @Lynchie (my name is Alvaro if you don't like varocarbas :)) OK.